# Update dynamic fields in OTRS over SOAP

Tags: php, soap, otrs

I spent several days trying to create or update a dynamic field of a ticket in OTRS via SOAP, but unfortunately to no success. I basically tried all variations of commands:

```
$response = $soapclient->__soapCall("Dispatch", array("user", "password",
                                    "TicketObject", "TicketUpdate",
                                    "DynamicField", array("name" => "fieldName", "value" => "Example"));
```

I tend to believe that this is not possible (OTRS version 5.0.14). Am I wrong? Is there a way to update dynamic fields of a ticket over SOAP and php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I managed to make it work. I post here my solution.

1. First, we have to fix (a bug?) in OTRS file bin/cgi-bin/rpc.pl and add to "dispatch" subroutine these two lines:

   `$CommonObject{DynamicField} = $Kernel::OM->Get('Kernel::System::DynamicField');
   $CommonObject{TicketDynamicObject}=$Kernel::OM->Get('Kernel::System::DynamicFieldValue');`
2. Then we have to get the dynamic field ID of the wanted dynamic field:

`$dynfield = $soap_client->__soapCall("Dispatch", array($user, $pass,
                                                       "DynamicField", "DynamicFieldGet",
                                                       "Name", $dynamic_field_name));`

3. Set dynamic field for the ticket (assuming a ticket with ticketId already exists) with $value:

   `$result = $soap_client->__soapCall("Dispatch", array($user, $pass, 
                           "TicketDynamicObject", "ValueSet",
                           "FieldID", $dynfield->ID,
                           "ObjectID", $ticketId,
                           "Value", array("0" => array("ValueText" => (string) $value)),
                           "UserID", $userId,
                           ));`

If a ticket is created, then we can subsequently set dynamic field for that ticket.

Does anyone have any idea why those two lines are missing in OTRS? Will it be fixed in new version of OTRS?